# Configuration Assistant (biee.py) Failed with Exit Value 1 at OBIEE12c

Tags: oracle, data-warehouse, obiee

During installation and configuration of obiee12c(12.2.1.4), configuration assistant failed with an error.
The following is the installation log.

> [2021-09-19T16:31:35.218+09:00] [bi] [NOTIFICATION] [] [oracle.bi.install.config.basesteps] [tid: 42] [ecid: 0000MTUM^f91Vctsoc7EDm1RztE2000004,0] Failed single shot step: BIEE with: Execution of [/u01/app/oracle/middleware/oracle_common/common/bin/wlst.sh, /u01/app/oracle/middleware/bi/modules/oracle.bi.configassistant/biee.py, /u01/app/oracle/middleware, /u01/app/oracle/middleware/user_projects/domains/bi, weblogic, Expanded, hxfpr371, 9502, 9503, ORACLE, oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver, jdbc:oracle:thin:@//:1521/, TST1, jdbc:oracle:thin:@//:1521/, ] failed with exit value 1
> [2021-09-19T16:31:35.219+09:00] [bi] [ERROR] [] [oracle.bi.install.config.actions] [tid: 42] [ecid: 0000MTUM^f91Vctsoc7EDm1RztE2000004,0] Non-skipped failure during configuration action: Execution of [/u01/app/oracle/middleware/oracle_common/common/bin/wlst.sh, /u01/app/oracle/middleware/bi/modules/oracle.bi.configassistant/biee.py, /u01/app/oracle/middleware, /u01/app/oracle/middleware/user_projects/domains/bi, weblogic, Expanded, hxfpr371, 9502, 9503, ORACLE, oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver, jdbc:oracle:thin:@//:1521/, TST1, jdbc:oracle:thin:@//:1521/, ] failed with exit value 1[[
> oracle.bi.exec.ExecutionStatusException: Execution of [/u01/app/oracle/middleware/oracle_common/common/bin/wlst.sh, /u01/app/oracle/middleware/bi/modules/oracle.bi.configassistant/biee.py, /u01/app/oracle/middleware, /u01/app/oracle/middleware/user_projects/domains/bi, weblogic, Expanded, hxfpr371, 9502, 9503, ORACLE, oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver, jdbc:oracle:thin:@//:1521/, TST1, jdbc:oracle:thin:@//:1521/, ] failed with exit value 1

```
at oracle.bi.exec.StdinProcess.runProcess(StdinProcess.java:106)
at oracle.bi.exec.ExecScript.executeScript(ExecScript.java:191)
at oracle.bi.exec.ExecScript.executeSynchronousScript(ExecScript.java:95)
at oracle.bi.exec.ExecWLST.executeWLSTScript(ExecWLST.java:62)
at oracle.bi.install.config.steps.WLSTStep.executeSingleShot(WLSTStep.java:55)
at oracle.bi.install.config.basesteps.SingleShotActionStep.execute(SingleShotActionStep.java:31)
at oracle.bi.install.config.basesteps.StepList.execute(StepList.java:85)
at oracle.bi.install.config.actions.BIConfigAction.doExecute(BIConfigAction.java:127)
at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.client.ConfigAction.execute(ConfigAction.java:405)
at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.action.TaskPerformer.run(TaskPerformer.java:88)
at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.action.TaskPerformer.startConfigAction(TaskPerformer.java:108)
at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.action.ActionRequest.perform(ActionRequest.java:15)
at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.action.RequestQueue.performSequentialExecution(RequestQueue.java:284)
at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.action.RequestQueue.perform(RequestQueue.java:260)
at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.standard.StandardConfigActionManager.start(StandardConfigActionManager.java:185)
at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.boot.ConfigurationExtension.kickstart(ConfigurationExtension.java:82)
at oracle.as.install.engine.modules.configuration.ConfigurationModule.run(ConfigurationModule.java:87)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Go into the log folder for that installation and grab the real log file of the config step to see what's going wrong. Your error above is simply "soemthing went wrong". Not the "what went wrong" part.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is due to a java configuration parameter i guess, try this before installation :

- go to « C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_192\jre\lib\security »
  ** replace this path with your own path
- edit the file « java.security » and replace this line :

securerandom.source=file:/dev/random

by this line :

```
securerandom.source=file:/dev/urandom
```

for more details : Doc ID 2221805.1